# Can I use win32gui to set the focus to a specific browser (firefox) tab?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I'm using the win32gui package for the first time. I combined 2 examples to printout all opened windows and set the focus to the first window, whose title matches with the wildcard.

That works fine, also with the active tab in my firefox browser. But when I try to set the focus to one of the non active tabs, ist doesn't work. Obviously the log_app_list() function contains only the name of the active tab, because this one occurs in the windowtitle of the browser window. How can I set the focus to another tab?

```
import win32gui
import re

class WindowMgr:
    """Encapsulates some calls to the winapi for window management"""

    def __init__ (self):
        """Constructor"""
        self._handle = None

    def find_window(self, class_name, window_name=None):
        """find a window by its class_name"""
        self._handle = win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)

    def _window_enum_callback(self, hwnd, wildcard):
        """Pass to win32gui.EnumWindows() to check all the opened windows"""
        if re.match(wildcard, str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) is not None:
            self._handle = hwnd

    def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
        """find a window whose title matches the wildcard regex"""
        self._handle = None
        win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)

    def set_foreground(self):
        """put the window in the foreground"""
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)

#################

def window_enum_handler(hwnd, resultList):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) != '':
        resultList.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

def get_app_list(handles=[]):
    mlst=[]
    win32gui.EnumWindows(window_enum_handler, handles)
    for handle in handles:
        mlst.append(handle)
    return mlst

def log_app_list():
    appwindows = get_app_list()
    for i in appwindows:
        print(i)

log_app_list()
w = WindowMgr()
w.find_window_wildcard(".*sssss*")
try:
    w.set_foreground()
except:
    print("no window does match with the wildcard")
```

Comment: Is your purpose to switch the browser tab? You can activate a specific pinned tab by Ctrl+Num Pad 1 through 0.

Comment: And when I want to identify the tab by a search phrase in its tab name?